# How to apache on Windows with linux path

Tags: windows, apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I'm trying to use apache on windows but i need that working with linux path like cPanel.
I tried to use like this:

```
Alias /home/username/public_html/ "c:/websites/username/"
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/username/public_html/"
    ServerName "www.domain.com"
    ServerAlias "domain.com"
    CustomLog "../logs/domain.com.log" common
    ErrorLog "../logs/domain.com_error.log"
    ServerAdmin admin@domain.com
</VirtualHost>

Warning: DocumentRoot [C:/home/username/public_html/] does not exist
```

And c: appear again.

I tried to create a directory with this path, c:/home/username/public_html/ and it's working, but the problem with my (ioncube encoded) script still the same.

This script check if the path is (xxxx/xxxx/xxxx) and need to return: True
But when the script check path it gets (xxxx\xxxx\xxxx) and return false.
This script, is encoded by ioncube, i can't change it.

Error messages:

```
Notice: Undefined index: FriendlyName in C:\home\username\public_html\portal\admin\configmodule.php on line 0
```

And again. We have C:\

It's running without any problems on Linux server (cPanel).

Is there anyway to use apache on windows but using linux path?

Comment: Maybe you could run Apache under [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)? I would not call it a good solution, but I guess it depends on your need to run this specific script under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

1. `DocumentRoot` is either an absolute path or relative to the `ServerRoot`, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot
2. The first parameter to `Alias` is the name of a path in the URL space, so the config you have defined will map a request to
   http://www.domain.com/home/username/public_html/
   to return content from the physical directory
   `C:/websites/username`
   and that's probably not what you want.
3. If your PHP code expects a physical path `/home/username/public_html/` to exist, then no amount of Apache config can fix that.